# OpenCv error in function Circle. Works on python 3.9 but dont work on python 3.8

Tags: python, opencv, python.net

Hi i trying to run some python program for image analyse.

I got configured environment on python 3.9 and there its works fine with anaconda, but now i need to run it on python 3.8 becouse i have to integrate this Py with Python.NET.
After running my program at 3.8 i got these error :

```
OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
  File "plot_new.py", line 221, in plotThick
    cv2.circle(im_with_pairs,tuple(point),10,magenta, thickness = 2)
  File "abc.py", line 212, in Analytics
    preferences = plot_new.plotThick(preferences, images, Ac, Ao, every_path, h, v)
  File "abc.py", line 307, in <module>
```

I dont know python, how can i know what going wrong ?
On the same pc, it works spyder with anacodna and python 3.9.
But these error showed on installed by me environment python 3.8.

Comment: Before calling `cv2.circle` what is `point`? what does it contain? and its data type?

Comment: depends on version of opencv. newer versions can handle more argument types as "equivalent". just pass `point.astype(int)` and that should work.

Comment: Hard to say ... Before this call we got array which contains something like this : 
 Ac = []
    for obj in keypoints:
        Ac.append(obj.pt) #KeypointX, Keypoint Y
    Ac = np.array(Ac,dtype=np.float32)
based on collection of images delivered to program